# Asymptotics of an integral depending on a parameter

Tags: integration, asymptotics

Given the integral
$\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{(1+a^2+x^2)^{\frac{\rho}{2}}(1+2\sqrt{E}x)}dx$, with $a,E>0$ and $\rho>2$, I want to know how to determine how it goes to 0 as $a\to +\infty$.
Maybe the answer is trivial, but I prefer being cautious

Comment: Do you mean $\sqrt Ex$ or $\sqrt{Ex}$ ?

Comment: Root only on $E$

Comment: In such cases, don't clutter with a constant like $2\sqrt E$. $b$ is good enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll write $b=2\sqrt E$ to simplify things.

To get a systematic expansion, write

\begin{eqnarray}
\int_1^a\frac1{(1+a^2+x^2)^\frac\rho2(1+bx)}\,\mathrm dx
&=&
\frac1{a^\rho b}\int_1^a\frac1{(1+\frac{x^2+1}{a^2})^\frac\rho2(1+\frac1{bx})x}\,\mathrm dx
\\
&=&
\frac1{a^\rho b}\int_1^a\sum_{j=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{-\frac\rho 2}j\left(\frac{x^2+1}{a^2}\right)^j\left(-\frac1{bx}\right)^k\frac1x\,\mathrm dx
\\
&=&
\sum_{j=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{n=0}^j\frac{(-1)^k}{a^{\rho+2j}b^{k+1}}\binom{-\frac\rho 2}j\binom jn\int_1^ax^{2n-k-1}\,\mathrm dx\;.
\\
&=&
\sum_{j=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{n=0}^j\frac{(-1)^k}{a^{\rho+2j}b^{k+1}}\binom{-\frac\rho 2}j\binom jn
\begin{cases}
\ln a&2n-k=0\;,\\
\frac{a^{2n-k}-1}{2n-k}&\text{otherwise}\;.
\end{cases}
\end{eqnarray}

The leading term is the one for $j=k=0$, which yields

$$
\frac{\ln a}{a^\rho b}\;,
$$

as in @stokes-line’s answer. The next term comes from contributions for $k=0$, $n=j\gt0$:

$$
\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac1{a^{\rho+2j}b}\binom{-\frac\rho 2}j\frac{a^{2j}}{2j}
=
-\frac1{a^\rho b}\frac\rho4\,_3F_2\left(1,1,\frac\rho2+1;2,2;-1\right)\;,
$$

where $_3F_2$ is a [generalized hypergeometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function), and for $j=0$, $k\gt0$:

$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{a^\rho b^{k+1}}\frac{-1}{-k}
=
-\frac{\ln\left(1+\frac1b\right)}{a^\rho b}\;.
$$

The term after that comes from $k=1$, $n=j$:

$$
-\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac1{a^{\rho+2j}b^2}\binom{-\frac\rho2} j\frac{a^{2j-1}}{2j-1}
=
\frac1{a^{\rho+1}b^2}\,_2F_1\left(-\frac12,\frac\rho2;\frac12;-1\right)\;.
$$

For the part beyond $a$, we need to expand in $\frac1x$ instead, yielding

\begin{eqnarray}
\int_a^\infty\frac1{(1+a^2+x^2)^\frac\rho2(1+bx)}\,\mathrm dx
&=&
\int_a^\infty\frac1{bx^{\rho+1}}\frac1{\left(1+\frac{a^2+1}{x^2}\right)^\frac\rho2\left(1+\frac1{bx}\right)}\,\mathrm dx
\\
&=&
\int_a^\infty\frac1{bx^{\rho+1}}\sum_{j=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{-\frac\rho2}j\left(\frac{a^2+1}{x^2}\right)^j\left(-\frac1{bx}\right)^k\,\mathrm dx
\\
&=&
\sum_{j=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{-\frac\rho2}j\frac{(-1)^k}{a^{\rho+2j+k}b^{k+1}}(a^2+1)^j\int_1^\infty t^{-(\rho+2j+k+1)}\,\mathrm dt
\\
&=&
\sum_{j=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{n=0}^j\binom{-\frac\rho2}j\binom jn\frac{(-1)^k}{a^{\rho+2j+k-2n}b^{k+1}}\frac1{\rho+2j+k}\;.
\end{eqnarray}

Here there is no logarithmic term; the first term comes from $k=0$, $n=j$:

$$
\sum_{j=0}^\infty\binom{-\frac\rho2}j\frac1{a^\rho b}\frac1{\rho+2j}=\frac1{a^\rho b}\frac1\rho\,_2F_1\left(\frac\rho2,\frac\rho2;\frac\rho2+1;-1\right)\;.
$$

The next term comes from $k=1$, $n=j$:

$$
-\sum_{j=0}^\infty\binom{-\frac\rho2}j\frac1{a^{\rho+1}b^2}\frac1{\rho+2j+1}=-\frac1{a^{\rho+1}b^2}\frac1{\rho+1}\,_2F_1\left(\frac\rho2,\frac{\rho+1}2;\frac{\rho+3}2;-1\right)\;.
$$

Thus, altogether we have the expansion

$$
\int_1^a\frac1{(1+a^2+x^2)^\frac\rho2(1+bx)}\,\mathrm dx
\\
=
\frac{\ln a-\ln\left(1+\frac1b\right)}{a^\rho b}
+
\left(\frac1\rho\,_2F_1\left(\frac\rho2,\frac\rho2;\frac\rho2+1;-1\right)-\frac\rho4\,_3F_2\left(1,1,\frac\rho2+1;2,2;-1\right)\right)\frac1{a^\rho b}
\\
+\left(_2F_1\left(-\frac12,\frac\rho2;\frac12;-1\right)-\frac1{\rho+1}\,_2F_1\left(\frac\rho2,\frac{\rho+1}2;\frac{\rho+3}2;-1\right)\right)\frac1{a^{\rho+1}b^2}
\\
+O\left(\frac1{a^{\rho+2}}\right)\;.
$$

For integer values of $\rho$, the hypergeometric series yield simple expressions. For instance, for $\rho=2$ the expansion takes the form

$$
\int_1^a\frac1{(1+a^2+x^2)(1+bx)}\,\mathrm dx
\\
=
\frac{\ln a-\ln\left(1+\frac1b\right)}{a^2 b}
+
\left(\frac12\,_2F_1\left(1,1;2;-1\right)-\frac12\,_3F_2\left(1,1,2;2,2;-1\right)\right)\frac1{a^2 b}
\\
+\left(_2F_1\left(-\frac12,1;\frac12;-1\right)-\frac13\,_2F_1\left(2,\frac32;\frac52;-1\right)\right)\frac1{a^3b^2}
\\
+O\left(\frac1{a^4}\right)\;.
\\
=
\frac{\ln a-\ln\left(1+\frac1b\right)}{a^2 b}
+\frac{\frac54+\frac\pi8}{a^3b^2}
+O\left(\frac1{a^4}\right)\;.
$$

The terms proportional to $\frac1{a^2b}$ cancel. For $\rho=3$, the result is

$$
\int_1^a\frac1{(1+a^2+x^2)^\frac32(1+bx)}\,\mathrm dx
\\
=
\frac{\ln a-\ln\left(1+\frac1b\right)}{a^3 b}
+
\left(\frac13\,_2F_1\left(\frac32,\frac32;\frac52;-1\right)-\frac34\,_3F_2\left(1,1,\frac52;2,2;-1\right)\right)\frac1{a^3 b}
\\
+\left(_2F_1\left(-\frac12,\frac32;\frac12;-1\right)-\frac14\,_2F_1\left(\frac32,2;3;-1\right)\right)\frac1{a^4b^2}
\\
+O\left(\frac1{a^5}\right)\;.
\\
=
\frac{\ln a-\ln\left(1+\frac1b\right)}{a^3 b}
+\frac{\ln2-1}{a^3 b}
+\frac2{a^4b^2}
+O\left(\frac1{a^5}\right)\;.
$$

For $\rho=4$, the result is

$$
\int_1^a\frac1{(1+a^2+x^2)^2(1+bx)}\,\mathrm dx
\\
=
\frac{\ln a-\ln\left(1+\frac1b\right)}{a^4 b}
+
\left(\frac14\,_2F_1\left(2,2;3;-1\right)-\,_3F_2\left(1,1,3;2,2;-1\right)\right)\frac1{a^4 b}
\\
+\left(_2F_1\left(-\frac12,2;\frac12;-1\right)-\frac15\,_2F_1\left(2,\frac52;\frac72;-1\right)\right)\frac1{a^5b^2}
\\
+O\left(\frac1{a^6}\right)\;.
\\
=
\frac{\ln a-\ln\left(1+\frac1b\right)}{a^4 b}
-{\frac12}\frac1{a^4 b}
+\frac{3\pi}4\frac1{a^5b^2}
+O\left(\frac1{a^6}\right)\;.
$$

For $\rho=5$, the result is

$$
\int_1^a\frac1{(1+a^2+x^2)^\frac52(1+bx)}\,\mathrm dx
\\
=
\frac{\ln a-\ln\left(1+\frac1b\right)}{a^5 b}
+
\left(\frac14\,_2F_1\left(\frac52,\frac52;\frac72;-1\right)-\,_3F_2\left(1,1,\frac72;2,2;-1\right)\right)\frac1{a^5 b}
\\
+\left(_2F_1\left(-\frac12,\frac52;\frac12;-1\right)-\frac15\,_2F_1\left(\frac52,3;4;-1\right)\right)\frac1{a^6b^2}
\\
+O\left(\frac1{a^7}\right)\;.
\\
=
\frac{\ln a-\ln\left(1+\frac1b\right)}{a^5 b}
+\frac{\ln2-\frac43}{a^5 b}
+\frac83\frac1{a^6b^2}
+O\left(\frac1{a^7}\right)\;.
$$

Comment: Thank you so much for this very detailed answer. I am interested only in the leading term, and this helped me understand the way it is computed. Instead, I didn't get why the next term comes from $k=0, n=j>0$

Comment: @SpuriousMatemagician: That's only the first part of the sentence; the next term comes from contributions from $k=0$, $n=j\gt0$ and from $j=0$, $k\gt0$. If you look at the powers of $a$ in the triple summation, there's $a^{\rho+2j}$ in the denominator, and the integration yields a term with $a^{2n-k}$ and a constant term.

Comment: Since $j$, $k$ and $n$ are all non-negative, for these exponents to add up to $a^\rho$ in the denominator, we must have $k=0$ and $n=j$ in the term $a^{2n-k}$ (and then $j\gt0$ because $k=j=0$ is the leading logarithmic term), or $j=0$ in the constant term (and then $k\gt0$ because $k=j=0$ is the leading logarithmic term). (And then of course there's a third contribution of order $a^{-\rho}$ that comes from the part of the integral beyond $a$.)

Comment: Ok. One more thing: let's say i am interested only in the leading term, When considering the part beyond $a$, after i have the series rapresentation, I can discard this part when related to the one below $a$, because here I have no logarithmic terms, right?

Answer (score 0):

The leading asymptotics can be found realizing that at large $a$ the integral comes from $1\lesssim x\lesssim a$ and is logarithmic in this range. As a result:
$$
I\sim \frac{\ln a}{2 \sqrt{E} a^\rho}.
$$

Comment: Can you go a little deeper in explaining this? If i gor it right, I have to split the integral in two parts: in $[1,a]$ and in $[a,+\infty]$. But then? Maybe in the first I can take out $a^2$ and write the Taylor expansion? Anyway i am not sure on how to proceed

Comment: It depends on what accuracy you want. Thats the leading term, to get it you need to observe that the integrand quickly decays at $x>a$ and for $1\lesssim x \lesssim a$ you need to keep dependence on $x$ only in the second term in the denominator. The rest gives subleading corrections.